# Oracle - Adding another bigfile datafile to a tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, tablespace

The default bigfile datafile with the attribute of auto-extend has run out of disk space and I cannot extend the HDD space of that specific drive. Is there any way to add another bigfile to the same tablespace or another way around this issue?

Comment: Bigfile tablespaces can only have one file.

Comment: If your tables contain LOB type columns, you can move those columns only to a different tablespace.

Comment: That is why I was looking for an alternative. I do not have any LOB datatypes as of now. Is there any way to move the tablespace data file to another drive or something along those lines?

Comment: You can move a tablespace to another drive with `ALTER DATABASE MOVE DATAFILE`, just check the documentation. Without knowing what kind of segments are inside the tablespace, I can give you only general advices to save space. You can empty the recycle bin, use compression, if it is the case, migrate indexes and adopt partitioned tables and split them across multiple tablespacce. That's all that comes to my mind right now.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try.